# JavaFX - Problema al recuperar una imagen de Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, javafx

Estoy usando una base de datos mysql, igual estoy usando JavaFx con el Scene Builder.

Mi problema es que he guardado una imagen en una base de datos y al intentar acceder a ella para insertarla en un ImageView, me sale un error:

> ERROR: "incompatible types: bufferedimage cannot be converted to image"

Este es el código:

```
ConexionBD con = new ConexionBD();
Connection cn = con.Conexion();


Statement prep2;
ResultSet result2;

String consulta2 = "SELECT Nombre,Logo FROM datosempresa";

try {
         prep2 = cn.createStatement();
         result2 = prep2.executeQuery(consulta2);


        if (result2.next()) {
            lblNombreEmpresa.setText(result2.getString(1)); //Funciona
            Image i = null;
            Blob blob = result2.getBlob("Logo");
            i = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream()); //ERROR!
            imgFotoEmpresa.setImage(i); //imgFotoEmpresa = ImageView
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PrincipalController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente tengo la respuesta.

En la linea de código donde tengo comentado *error* simplemente hay que cambiarla por:

`i = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream()), null);`

Esto es para capturar una imagen guardada en una base de datos MYSQL (BLOB), e insertar la imagen en `ImageView`.

Comment: No es necesario que edites el titulo, acepta tu propia respuesta como correcta

Comment: click en el check verde del costado de esta respuesta :D